# video won't play in correct colours

Tags: videos

[image: this is what it looks like when i run an mp4 file]

im not sure how to get logs or code and stuff as im new to linux but i really need help. this isn't the file because i have tried it will multiple files and i've tried those files on other devices.
any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Mayeb install some media codecs:
`apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras libavcodec-extra`

Answer (score 0):

You can try typing this command in a terminal.

**sudo apt-get remove gstreamer1.0-vaapi**

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030257/video-player-in-18-04-shows-a-psychedelic-mixture-instead-of-a-clear-video) is the solution that has worked for me.